# Sub-column reordering in bootstrap column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns

I have a basic 3 columns layout (https://jsfiddle.net/mjaa64cj/) but am unable to swap the text/image placement on large screens of the elements in the last column. On mobile/tablet devices the columns stack ok.
[Screenshot of the expected layout](http://1drv.ms/1GoQDOm)
I'm using bootstrap 3.2. Checkout the fiddle for details.
Here's the html code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row front">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="holder.js/350x350" />
      <h2>I, Roommate</h2>
      <p>Oh sure! Blame the wizards! Bender, this is Fry's decision… and he made it wrong. So it's time for us to interfere in his life. Man, I'm sore all over. I feel like I just went ten rounds with mighty Thor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>The Farnsworth Parabox</h2>
      <p>I just told you! You've killed me! With a warning label this big, you know they gotta be fun! When will that be? Man, I'm sore all over. I feel like I just went ten rounds with mighty Thor. Mor's good friend, Richard Nixon. Say it in Russian</p>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="holder.js/350x350" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
          <h2>A Pharaoh to Remember</h2>
          <p>With a warning label this big, you know they gotta be fun! Moving along… Bender, this is Fry's decision… and he made it wrong. So it's time for us to interfere in his life. Morbo can't understand his teleprompter because he forgot how you say that letter that's shaped like a man wearing a hat. Why would I want to know that.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
          <img class="img-responsive  col-sm-push-4" src="holder.js/350x350" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have tried with push/pull the elements in the 3rd column, but the content is just overflowing beyond the edge of the screen or over the 2nd column.
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Not possible to swap that way vertically......maybe you will need to duplicate the info and use visible / hidden. Or a simple Jquery function

Comment: My 5 cents were that if you add the push/pull classes the order would swap, just as it is possible for top level columns like:    <div class="col-lg-12 col-lg-push-12 col-sm-12">
                 <h2>...</h2>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-lg-pull-12 col-sm-12">
                <img class="img-responsive  col-sm-push-4" src="holder.js/350x350" />
            </div>